# When Reviewing Re-Open Candidates, The Message Prompt is Wrong

Tags: bug

While reviewing re-open question candidates, I clicked the 'Leave Closed' button. I was then prompted with a message, asking me if I'd like to nominate the question for 'Reopen'.

<strike>While the pop-up message was completely erroneous, the action, that is clicking 'OK', worked as expected.</strike>

**EDIT:** The net effect of this bug was that I wanted to leave [a certain question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/10373/437) closed, but the review system honored my button click as if I wanted to reopen that question.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184603/clicking-leave-closed-shows-the-reopen-pop-up

Comment: Or possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185905/167443 :-P

Comment: It sounds like this is now fixed. If someone can confirm, please let me know and I'll mark this as fixed or escalate it up to the devs.

Comment: Already been asked on SO Meta
